# Trying to create application using asp.net mvc with entity framework,but returns zero record

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to learn asp.net mvc by doing hands-on. So i started with very small web application using asp.net mvc along with entity framework to access sql server.

I created one table in sql server localdb

```
USE Ourlifestory ;  
GO 
create table staticlocations(
LocationID int primary key,
LocationName varchar(30),
Tripdate datetime,
Locationimage image)
```

---

Below is the connection string

```
<add name="OurLifeStoryDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=Ourlifesotry;          Integrated Security=True;" />
```

---

DBContext class :

```
public class OurLifeStoryDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public OurLifeStoryDBContext()
            : base("name=OurLifeStoryDBContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<StaticLocations> Location { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Model class for one table :

```
[Table("staticlocations")]
    public class StaticLocations
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public DateTime Tripdate { get; set; }
        //[Column(TypeName="image")]
        //public byte[] LocationImage { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Controller action method accessing this dbcontext :

```
public ActionResult GetLocationDetails(int locationID)
        {
            var dbContext = new OurLifeStoryDBContext();
            var location = dbContext.Location.ToList();
            return View("_GetLocationDetails");
        }
```

But in above action method on the below line ,

var location = dbContext.Location.ToList();

i am getting zero records though i am very i have one record which i manually inserted through insert statement in database.

Any thoughts what i am missing here?

Comment: Maybe youre not passing `location` to the view? `return View("_GetLocationDetails", location);`

Comment: I agree with @Joseph, and not sure if this is really a typo or if it even matters: `Initial Catalog=Ourlifesotry;` in your connection string should be `Initial Catalog=Ourlifestory;`.

Comment: Try to debug and take a look if `location` variable contains no results.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, you spot on cool , typo is the issue. I corrected the database name and it fetches the data. I am able to fetch value...

Comment: @Joseph, agree i need to pass location to the view but i stuck with fetching data so did not concentrate on that particular line. thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, will it not throw error if the data base name is typed wrongly ?

Comment: @CodeLearner No, it won't. That's because as far as the system knows, you might have another database with that name so when it finds no matching database it will just return nothing.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, thanks Patel. How i can mark you answered my question ? guess there is provision to that in SO

Comment: It's alright, its a small typo not a coding solution, glad I could help.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL you should post it as a solution so when people look for similar answers in the future it will help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why nothing was returned, there was a typo in your connection string:

```
Initial Catalog=Ourlifesotry;
```

in your connection string should be

```
Initial Catalog=Ourlifestory;
```

Why did it not give any "error" or indication?

That's because Entity Framework cannot detect if you spelled your database name wrong. For all it knows, your database could be called "misssssspelled".

Also, when there is no existing database with the provided name, instead of an error value/warning, it will simply return nothing instead.